# Load library by passing parameter to constructor in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter. I defined a library in code-igniter and is expecting a parameter in its constructor.This is my library code -

```
################# [My Library Code Test_lib.php ] ########################
<?php
class Test_lib
{
var $params;
public function __construct($params)
{
    $this->params = $params;
    echo $this->params;
}
}
```

In codeigniter documentation, it is mentioned that you can pass the parameter in the second argument.
So,I am initializing it from controller as below -

```
<?php
class Test_cont extends CI_Controller {
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

function test()
{
    $params = "abc";
    $this->load->library("test_lib",$params);
}
}
```

I am getting following error -

A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Warning Message: Missing argument.....

Please assist.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`$params` must be an array. [From the documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html):

> In the library loading function you can dynamically pass data as an array via the second parameter and it will be passed to your class constructor:
>
> ```
> $params = array('type' => 'large', 'color' => 'red');
>
> $this->load->library('Someclass', $params);
> ```

In your case, you want to do something like this:

```
function test()
{
    $params[] = "abc"; // $params is an array
    $this->load->library("test_lib",$params);
}
```

Comment: if my constructor is like function __construct($param1 = null, $param2 = null, $param3 = null) then how to pass parameters???/

Comment: mean if i dont want to pass an array.

Comment: You can pass NULLs by default.

Answer (score 7):

Class Test_lib

```
################# [My Library Code Test_lib.php ] ########################
<?php

class Test_lib {

  var $parameter1;
  var $parameter2;
  var $parameter3;

  public function __construct($parameters) {

    /* array assoc */
    $this->parameter1 = $parameters['argument1'];
    $this->parameter2 = $parameters['argument2'];
    $this->parameter3 = $parameters['argument3'];

    /* object */
    $oParameters = (object) $parameters;

    $this->parameter1 = $oParameters->argument1;
    $this->parameter2 = $oParameters->argument2;
    $this->parameter3 = $oParameters->argument3;

  }

}
```

Class Controller

```
<?php

  class Test_cont extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
      parent::__construct();
    }

    function test() {

      $data = array( // array assoc
        'argument1' => 'String 1',
        'argument2' => 'String 2',
        'argument3' => 'String 3'
      );

      $this->load->library("Test_lib", $data);

      return $this->Test_lib->parameter1;

    }

    echo $this->test(); // String 1

  }
```

Answer (score 6):

You just need to modify the **$params** from a variable to array. hope this will work

```
function test()
{
    $params = array(1=>'abc');
    $this->load->library('test_lib',$params);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Load custom libarary

```
class custom_library
{
    public $CI, $user_data = array();
    private $_user_id = 0;
    
    public function __construct(){
        $this->CI = & get_instance();
        $this->user_id = $this->CI->user_data['user_id'];
    }
    
    function test(){
        echo $this->user_id;
    }
}

$this->load->library('custom_library');
$this->custom_library->user_data = $this->user_data;
```